# "Zoom in" on a violinplot whilst keeping accurate quartile lines (matplotlib/seaborn)

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

TL;DR: How can I get a subrange of a violinplot whilst keeping accurate quartile lines?

I am using seaborn violinplots to make static charts for a report, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to redraw a particular area between limits whilst retaining the 25/median/75 quartile lines of the *original* dataset.

Here's my example dataset as a violin. The 25/median/75 values are left side: 1.0/5.0/9.0; right side: 2.0/5.0/9.0

[image: An example split violin plot with range 0 to 700; the neck is extremely long and very little useful information is discernible. It looks like an upside-down T-pin]

My data has such a long tail that all the useful info is scrunched up into a tiny area. I want to ignore (but not throw away) the tail and show a closer look at the interesting bit.

I tried to reset the ylim using `ax.set(ylim=(0, upp))`, but the resultant graph is not great: it's jaggy and the inner lines don't meet the violin edge.

[image: A split violin chart showing same data as above but truncated between range 0 to 25. It's easier to see the info but the chart still does not look good - the edges aren't smooth and the quantile lines don't cross the entire violin]

Is there a way to reset the y-axis limits but get a better quality result?

Next I tried to cut off the tail by dropping values from the dataset. I dropped anything over the 97th centile. The violin looks way better, but the quartile lines have been recalculated for this new dataset. They're showing a median of about 4, not 5 as per the original dataset.

[image: A split violin plot between ranges 0 to 25. It shows smoother detail than the second plot above, however the median line is not correct]

I'm using inner="quartile", so the code that gets called in Seaborn is _ViolinPlotter::draw_quartiles

```
def draw_quartiles(self, ax, data, support, density, center, split=False):
        """Draw the quartiles as lines at width of density."""
        q25, q50, q75 = np.percentile(data, [25, 50, 75])

        self.draw_to_density(ax, center, q25, support, density, split,
                             linewidth=self.linewidth,
                             dashes=[self.linewidth * 1.5] * 2)
```

As you can see, it assumes (understandably) that one wants to draw the quartile lines at percentiles 25, 50 and 75. It'd be amazeballs if there was a way I could call draw_to_density with my own values (is there?).

At the moment, I am attempting to manually adjust the position of the lines. It's trivial to figure out & set the y-values:

```
for l in ax.lines:
    l.set_ydata(<get correct quartile value from original dataset>)
```

but I'm finding it hard to figure out the limits for x, i.e. the density of the distribution at the quartiles. It seems to involve gaussian kde, and tbh it's getting hacky and inelegant at this point. Is there an easy way to calculate how long each line should be?

[image: A split violin plot, with y-axis between 0 to 25; the quartile lines have the correct y-values, but the lines extend past or do not meet the edges of the violin]

What do you suggest?
Thanks for your help

- Lnr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W/ Thanks to @JohanC.

added `gridsize=1000` to the params of the violinplot and used `ax.set(ylim=(0, upp))` to resize the y-axis to show the range from 0 to upp where upp is the upper limit. Much prettier lookin' graph:

[image: A split violin plot showing smooth edges and accurate quartile lines]