# How to add new Quartile lines to a violinplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to adjust the quartile lines in a seaborns violinplot. The violinplot is created from only a subset of the data, and I want

I want to "zoom in" to my violinplot, but show the actual quantile values from all original data.

How do I move the quantile lines and fit them into the violinplot? I guess I need the lower and upper bound at the given position x to fit my line into the plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
d = pd.Series([-500,-200,10,100,1000])
#75% Quantile of original Data
original_75_quant = np.quantile(d,.75) # 100
# Zoom in Violinplot, only show values >0
sns.violinplot(d[d>0],inner="quart")
#where quantile should be actually drawn
plt.axvline(x=original_75_quant,color="yellow",label="original quantile")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64467980/zoom-in-on-a-violinplot-whilst-keeping-accurate-quartile-lines-matplotlib-sea), but it doesn't consider adding new quartile lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the `Path` of the violin and used that to clip the line.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
d = np.array([-500, -200, 10, 100, 1000])

# 75% Quantile of original Data
original_75_quant = np.quantile(d, .75)  # 100

# Zoom in Violinplot, only show values >0
ax = sns.violinplot(x=d[d > 0], inner="quart")

# where quantile should be actually drawn
line75 = ax.axvline(x=original_75_quant, color="gold", label="original quantile")
patch = PathPatch(ax.collections[0].get_paths()[0], transform=ax.transData)
line75.set_clip_path(patch) # clip the line by the form of the violin

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: violinplot with added quantile line]

Comment: Perfect. Thats what i was looking for. thank you very much!